# I can't able to take my Images to new activity that are loaded from SD card

Tags: android, image, gridview, android-gallery

Image activity

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context context;
Bitmap bm;

ArrayList<String>images = new ArrayList<String>();



//  Integer[] images;
void add(String path) {
    images.add(path);
}


public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return images;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    if (convertView == null) {
        //     imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        //   imageView.setImageBitmap(images);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(240, 240));
        return imageView;
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;

    }
     bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(images.get(position), 220, 220);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
return imageView;
}

private Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    Bitmap bm = null;
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    return bm;
}
public int calculateInSampleSize(

        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
}
```

Main Activity

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("id", position);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

FullImageActivity

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_image);

    Intent i=getIntent();

    int position= i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter= new ImageAdapter(this);





    ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

     imageView.setImageBitmap(imageAdapter.bm); \\here I have to show my images that are read from Storage


}
```

I can't able to pass it properly because my arraylist are string. I tried many ways that I know but that not work properly. I tried from internet also but not working.
I can't show my images through fullimage activity. I read images from SD card so It not showing in full view. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `FullImageActivity` you create a new instance  of the `ImageAdapter` and the `ArrayList<String> images` of this instance is empty since you never call `ImageAdapter.add()`. Therefore, `getCount()` returns 0 and `getView()` is never triggered so your bitmap is null at this point. I'd suggest that you read a bit more about object instantiation in Java and later about how to pass data from one Activity to another in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not executing properly because it is not setup correctly.
First thing's first, consider using Picasso or Glide or UniversalImageLoader for loading your images into the placeholders to avoid making a clunky user experience scrolling through images.

Secondly, passing the position to the second activity is not your goal. You are trying to pass the image. So pass the image lol,

```
First on your getItem()
```

you should return the individual image based on position images.get(position)

rather then return images.

Secondly in your click handler

Either pass it as an extra like

```
intent.addExtra(myAdapter.getItem(position))
```

or if you have the list already just do

```
intent.addExtra(myList.get(position))

or simply cheat with ActivityTwo.imageToShow = myList.get(position)
startActivityTwo
```

anyone of these will work fine.

Comment: yeah your right. GridView look horrible. I don't know how to correct it. I tried many things. still not working fine

Comment: I will try getItem() bro........ let me try and tell you. If you have any sample code for gridview. please suggest me and tell me where to use

Comment: I can't write your sample project for you, but if you have specific questions about the above answer that I provided, I'm happy to clarify

Comment: I mean where can I correct my code to get proper view and also how to correct. I am not sure where to correct.

Comment: Please read my answer llyas. I gave you step by step guide. you have a getItem() method in your adapter. Update it to return the position of the array, not the entire array itself. You have a place where you fill in the extra of an Intent, put the object in the intent not the position. I literally gave you step by step above. I'm confused at why you are asking for more detail on this?

Comment: bro. again giving problem. I tried hard but still i can't able to pass my image from main activity to another activity

Comment: I tried my best from myself and internet. but nothing works.

Comment: Then update your question to show the code with my recommended changes and I will help you see what is the next thing that you have incorrect. I can't help without seeing the latest code.

Comment: @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return images.get(position);
    }

Comment: i get error in this. I can't able to get the image to image view

Comment: ArrayList<String>images = new ArrayList<String>();
    void add(String path) {
        images.add(path);
    }
@Override public Object getItem(int position) { return images.get(position); }

Comment: Bro It's finally works :D thank you for your suggestion. I used two imageAdapter that's the problem

Comment: bro  @Sam... check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931282/save-images-to-internal-storage-from-gridview)